# Ordering CollectionReference Firease

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using a CollectionReference to read all the documents in my collection.

```
CollectionReference MyItems = db.collection( "Users" );
MyItems .get().addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        if (task.getResult()!=null) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                fetchItems(document.getString("ItemID"));
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
    }
} );
```

I was wondering if there is an option to order the documents in this collection by some field such as:

```
CollectionReference MyItems = db.collection( "Users" ).orderBy( "Date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING );
MyItems .get().addOnCompleteListener( task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        if (task.getResult()!=null) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                fetchItems(document.getString("ItemID"));
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.d("", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
    }
} );
```

However it doesnt work since I get this error in my first line (CollectionReference MyItems...):

[image]

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "order the document in it before".  Could you show an example of what you're trying to accomplish?  Are you sure orderBy is not going to work?

Comment: I updated what I tried without success tho

Comment: Please copy the exact error message, don't paraphrase it. Also: on what exact statement do you get that error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CollectionReference` is a subclass of `Query`.  In this case, you are building a `Query` object, not a `CollectionReference`, so you need to type is correctly:

```
Query MyItems = db.collection( "Users" ).orderBy( "Date", Query.Direction.ASCENDING );
```